# Role Hierarchy - Restrict current user from upgrading his role or other user's role to a role for which he doesn't have the privilege

Tags: permissions, roles, abp

In ABP IO, as part of role management, consider the following role hierarchy is defined.

1. Super admin
2. Manager - should be able to upgrade Staff as Manager or Member as Staff but cannot upgrade/downgrade his own role. Even for Staff or Member, he should not have the privilege to upgrade as Super admin.
3. Staff
4. Member

When I log in as a Manager and I try to edit my own role, it is allowing me to upgrade as Super admin as shown below

[image]

How do I prevent the current user from upgrading his role or other user's role to a role for which he doesn't have the privilege.